# Configuration of switchable

Tags: configuration, illegalargumentexception, magnolia

I have a switchble field inside a multifiled. This is how the dialog looks like:

[image: enter imafge description here]

See below my configuration (Two images because the configuration is quite extensive):
[image]
[image]

The problem is that the dialog works correctly but when I try to save the values I get the following error:

[image]

Is everything ok with my configuration? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce same issue in other dialog so it looks like a bug to me. Please log it at [Magnolia's jira](http://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI).

In the mean time it should work fine if you change your config from `SwitchableFieldDefinition` to `info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.SelectFieldDefinition`.

Field will show up as a combo rather then radio checkbox, but result will be the same, user can choose just one option.

HTH,
Jan